# How to check if portion of memory has been allocated using C++ allocator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation, memmove

**Is there a way to determine if specific part of memory is contained in a single C++ allocated block? And in release mode unfortunately. And ideally on both Windows and Mac.**

I have a really problematic bug here - it appears only in release mode, it's extremely hard to simulate, multithreaded and usually destroyes stack. It seems that it is caused by call to memmove and my only guess is that it is replacing a huge portion of memory and before the access violation occurs it usually already replaces the stack.

The algorithm is extremely complex and this happens literally from time to time, no idea how to effectively simulate it, so my only idea is to implant a test into memmove to ensure the arguments are correct. Each portion should be located in a single alloctor block of course, so I need to check if specificed block being replaced is correct.

Comment: valgrind on Mac; Insure or Purify on Windows

Comment: Run it in a debugger, put a conditional breakpoint on the suspect memmove such that if it tries to move a large amount, you break and can see what happened.

Comment: Purify is nice for Linux, i know that was not the question...

Comment: Why can't you add assertions on block sizes and NULL pointers before memmove so you can break if any of those conditions occur? As already mentioned by aschepler, if this same bug is present on both systems, valgrind should be able to catch it nicely.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check the tools. @Dave: as I explained, it's far from that simple. No NULLs, breakpoints... this is more nonstandard.